# InDesign: grep to replace space with EN space after full stops between sentences

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

The title describes the issue. I am using this query `([\l\u])\.\s([\l\u])` and replacing with `$1.~>$2` and it works, BUT this also picks up paragraphs returns, probably because of the `\s` in the first string. Any way to rewrite this first string to skip paragraph returns?

What the client wants basicly (and its a very large document), is to increase spacing between sentences. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since CS6, InDesign has supported the Perl wildcards `\v` and `\h` to specifically match vertical and horizontal whitespace, respectively.

`\h` matches all kinds of spaces and tabs, *but not line and paragraph breaks*, so it fits your needs perfectly: simply replace `\s` with `\h` and it should work as intended.

InDesignSecrets has [a brief article](https://indesignsecrets.com/selecting-horizontal-vertical-spaces-grep.php) on these two wildcards as well, which I suggest you have a look at.